# How to display the draggable div width in a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some draggable div and each div has a text box to display the width of that div width, I don't get an idea to display it. Here the script is used for dragging the div in script variable p store the div width after dragging
How can I do this?

```js
 $(function () {
            var container = $('.middletablediv'),
                base = null,
                handle = $('.handle'),
                isResizing = false;

            handle.on('mousedown', function (e) {
                base = $(this).closest(".timescalebase");
                isResizing = true;
                lastDownX = e.clientX;
            });

            $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
                // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
                if (!isResizing)
                    return;

                var p = (e.clientX - base.offset().left);

                base.css('width', p);

            }).on('mouseup', function (e) {
                // stop resizing
                isResizing = false;

            });
            $("#width1").val("p");
        })
```

```css
  .activelevel1 {
        background-color: red;
        }

        .timescalebase {
        margin-top: 13px;
        height: 7px;
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 5px;
        }

        .handle {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 8px;
        cursor: w-resize;
        background-color: black;
        }
```

```html
 <html>
   <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
<div id="container" style="width:100%;margin-top:25px;">
        <div id="timebase1" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div><input id="startvalue1" type="text" name="number" value="200" min="1" >
        <div id="width1" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div><input id="startvalue1" type="text" name="number" value="200" min="1" >
        <div id="width2" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div><input id="width3" type="text" name="number" value="200" min="1" >
        <div id="timebase4" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div><input id="width4" type="text" name="number" value="200" min="1" >
    </div>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when there's plenty of decent sliders. [jQueryUI has one](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove the **duplicate** IDs from your HTML. You should always have unique IDs in your HTML. You have "startvalue1" more than once. Also notice that i have assigned an ID for each one of your `<input>` that has a prefix derived from the `<div>` with your slider. In that way i can access specifically what i want easily without fears of later HTML additions interfering with my code.

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;margin-top:25px;">
  <div id="timebase1" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
      <div class="handle"></div>
  </div>
  <input id="timebase1_value" type="text" name="number" value="200" min="1" >

  <div id="width1" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
      <div class="handle"></div>
  </div>
  <input id="width1_value" type="text" name="number" value="200" min="1" >

  <div id="width2" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
      <div class="handle"></div>
  </div>
  <input id="width2_value" type="text" name="number" value="200" min="1" >

  <div id="timebase4" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
      <div class="handle"></div>
  </div>
  <input id="timebase4_value" type="text" name="number" value="200" min="1" >
</div>
```

Here is the Updated code for what you need. Now that we do not have Duplicate IDs , we just need to change the Value. The only addition is the following line

```
jQuery('#' + base[0].id + '_value').val(p);
```

I have also removed the forgotten

```
$("#width1").val("p");
```

you had there.

```
 $(function () {
     var container = $('.middletablediv'),
         base = null,
         handle = $('.handle'),
         isResizing = false;

     handle.on('mousedown', function (e) {
         base = $(this).closest(".timescalebase");
         isResizing = true;
         lastDownX = e.clientX;
     });

     $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
         // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
         if (!isResizing)
             return;

         var p = (e.clientX - base.offset().left);
         jQuery('#' + base[0].id + '_value').val(p);

         base.css('width', p);

     }).on('mouseup', function (e) {
         // stop resizing
         isResizing = false;

     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on doing it the way you've started, you have to pass the current target in a variable on `mousedown` and then use that `currentTarget` var to `mousemove`.

Then you set the input value based on that target.
`currentTarget.parent().next('input').val(p);`

```js
 $(function () {
            var container = $('.middletablediv'),
                base = null,
                handle = $('.handle'),
                isResizing = false,
                currentTarget;
                


            handle.on('mousedown', function (e) {
                base = $(this).closest(".timescalebase");
                isResizing = true;
                lastDownX = e.clientX;
                currentTarget = $(e.target)
            });

            $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
                // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
                if (!isResizing)
                    return;

                var p = (e.clientX - base.offset().left);

                base.css('width', p);
                currentTarget.parent().next('input').val(p);

            }).on('mouseup', function (e) {
                // stop resizing
                isResizing = false;
            });
            $("#width1").val("p");
        })
```

```css
  .activelevel1 {
        background-color: red;
        }

        .timescalebase {
        margin-top: 13px;
        height: 7px;
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 5px;
        }

        .handle {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 8px;
        cursor: w-resize;
        background-color: black;
        }
```

```html
 <html>
   <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
<div id="container" style="width:100%;margin-top:25px;">
        <div id="timebase1" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div><input id="startvalue1" type="text" name="number" value="200" min="1" >
        <div id="width1" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div><input id="startvalue1" type="text" name="number" value="200" min="1" >
        <div id="width2" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div><input id="width3" type="text" name="number" value="200" min="1" >
        <div id="timebase4" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div><input id="width4" type="text" name="number" value="200" min="1" >
    </div>
       </body>
     </html>
```